# Issue while getting data from a web service (Angular 4)

Tags: arrays, angular, web-services, typescript, get

I'm trying to get data from web service API

All i get is the data on console.

the web service requires ID so i post the id first and then getting data that related to that ID inside the web service, this is my component.

HTML:

```
<form #educationForm="ngForm" method="post">
    <select [(ngModel)]="type_id"  name="type_id" class="rounded-inputs20  col-md-2"  id="getGrades">
        <option selected="selected">Education type...</option>
        <option  id="" *ngFor="let type_id of name_en" [ngValue]="type_id.id">{{type_id.name_en}}</option>
    </select>
</form>

<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous"/>
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button (click)="onSubmitGrade(educationForm)"  value="next"/>

<fieldset>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center row schools">
        <div class="col-md-6"  *ngFor="let grade of grades">
            <h6 style="font-size: 26px;" name="grades"> 
            {{grade.name}}<input [value]="grade.id" id="select-all-grades6" type="checkbox">  
            </h6>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

TS:

```
private educationType() {
return this._http.get('https://crm.easyschools.org/api/
en/schools/create/educationtypes')
  .subscribe(type_id => {
    this.id = type_id.id;
    this.name_en = type_id.data;
    console.log(type_id.data);
  });
}

onSubmitGrade(form: NgForm) {
let formData: FormData = new FormData();
// debugger;
formData.append('education_type_id', this.type_id);
this._http.post('https://crm.easyschools.org/api/en/schools/
create/getgrades', formData)
  .subscribe(grades => {
    // this.type_id = this.education_type_id;
    this.id = this.type_id.id;
    this.name = grades.data;
    console.log(grades.data);
  }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

The response i get from the console is:

```
(13) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{id: 11, name: "Elementary", lessons_per_day: 5, lesson_duration: 
"08:21:20", day_start_at: "08:24:27", …}
1
:
{id: 13, name: "Secondary", lessons_per_day: 6, lesson_duration: 
"09:25:25", day_start_at: "10:29:00", …}
2
:
{id: 16, name: "Castor Sharp", lessons_per_day: 12, lesson_duration: 
"00:00:12", day_start_at: "17:30:00", …}
3
:
{id: 17, name: "Ifeoma Cochran", lessons_per_day: 12, lesson_duration: 
"00:00:04", day_start_at: "23:09:00", …}
4
:
{id: 18, name: "Jermaine Tyson", lessons_per_day: 12, lesson_duration: 
"00:00:14", day_start_at: "18:01:00", …}
5
:
{id: 19, name: "Quin Wells", lessons_per_day: 12, lesson_duration: 
"00:00:04", day_start_at: "11:25:00", …}
6
:
{id: 20, name: "Hiram Coffey", lessons_per_day: 12, lesson_duration: 
"00:00:04", day_start_at: "06:14:00", …}
7
:
{id: 21, name: "Shad Floyd", lessons_per_day: 12, lesson_duration: 
"00:00:04", day_start_at: "21:01:00", …}
8
:
{id: 22, name: "Oleg Ball", lessons_per_day: 12, lesson_duration: 
"00:00:41", day_start_at: "00:08:00", …}
9
:
{id: 23, name: "Ivory Gates", lessons_per_day: 12, lesson_duration: 
"00:00:41", day_start_at: "16:33:00", …}
10
:
{id: 24, name: "Serina Edwards", lessons_per_day: 12, lesson_duration: 
"00:00:41", day_start_at: "13:51:00", …}
11
:
{id: 25, name: "dsos", lessons_per_day: 44, lesson_duration: 
"00:00:45", 
day_start_at: "12:30:00", …}
12
: 
{id: 26, name: "Nissim Hurley", lessons_per_day: 12, lesson_duration: 
"00:00:04", day_start_at: "10:33:00", …}
length
:
13
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

I need to be able to display the data on the console on the screen, but my code is not showing anything.
Feel free to use the API links to test and show me what is missing in my code.

Comment: what do you need

Comment: @Sajeetharan for the console response to be able to display it on the screen via data binding but my code is not showing anything

Comment: you mean template does not dipslay anything?

Comment: @Sajeetharan exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see anywhere you have grades declared in your template, have a variable declared and assign the response data to the variable.

```
grades :any = [];
```

and then

```
this._http.post('https://crm.easyschools.org/api/en/schools/ create/getgrades', formData) .subscribe(result=> { this.grades = result.data;}, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => { console.log(err); }); }
```

or with the existing template replace grades with name,

```
 <div class="col-md-6"  *ngFor="let grade of name"
```

Comment: I did that and its not working as well, what should i write inside the binding after doing what u wrote, {{grade.name}}?

Comment: can you post what you see when you put console.log(JSON.stringify(this.grades)) in ts.

Comment: @MohamedWahshey can u try this one ...

`grades: any;

onSubmitGrade(form: NgForm) {
let formData: FormData = new FormData();
// debugger;
formData.append('education_type_id', this.type_id);
this._http.post('https://crm.easyschools.org/api/en/schools/
create/getgrades', formData)
  .subscribe(result=> {
    this.grades = result.data;
    console.log(result.data);
  }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}`

Comment: @Sajeetharan  there is an issue with my pc connection so i cannot try the response now but i get json array with all the data regarding the chosen type id from the select tag

Comment: @Sajeetharan ok i will try this but what about the binding inside html template? Should i write grade.name?

Comment: @MohamedWahshey Yes everything remains the same except grade. check the edited answer. as akshay mentioned

Comment: I updated the question, posted the response @Sajeetharan and tried what akshay said, i was already able to log in the console my issue is i cannot display it on the screen